# Okular: File -> Properties -> Optimized?

Tags: kde, pdf, okular, document

If you open a PDF file in Okular and choose the menu entry "File -> Properties", a list of the current file's various properties is displayed. Among them is the entry

> Optimized: <Yes|No>

What does it mean for a PDF file to be "optimized"? I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Optimized" in the context of PDF means "Optimized for fast web view". The internal structure of such a document is changed, so that after downloading "the overhead", individual pages can be displayed without the need to download the complete document (keyword bytestream). This has big advantages with documents sporting several hundred or thousand pages.

The conditions for a document to be optimized for fast web view are described in the Portable Document Format Reference (and its successor ISO 32000), which are part of the Documentation of the Acrobat SDK, downloadable from the Adobe website.